# Pros and cons of representing routes as legs or stops?

Tags: design, algorithms, class-design, domain-model, graph

What are some pros and cons of representing routes as legs or as stops?

A leg is a departure and arrival location, a departure time and a duration (or an arrival time and a duration).

A stop is an arrival time, a location, and a departure time.

The domain I'm modelling is a marketplace where people describe the route they're planning, then, suppliers can bid on routes they're interested in. We have an existing system that is using stops. We don't have any major problems with stops, but I'm wondering if using legs would be better, hence I'm wondering if there are pros or cons I'm not aware of.

I searched for "software design trip modelling", "software design route modelling", "software trip leg stop", and all I found is documentation on a tool by Oracle and model railroad software.

I do understand that legs and stops are duals of each other, but in the database, there should be a single representation. https://dba.stackexchange.com/ is silent on the matter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are the connections between locations are represented in your current system based on "stops"?

Comment: Maybe the best thing to do is to try and get some domain experts (people working in the industry you're building the software for) and try to figure out how they think about it from the business perspective (e.g. are they talking and planning in terms of legs or stops and why, do they have to work around the fact that the current system uses a step-based representation or not, do they have their own terminology, etc.)

Comment: Eric Evans the author of "Domain Driven Design" https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00794TAUG/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i0 uses Cargo shipping as example problem domain in his book and multiple of his presentations, you can find on youtube. It might worth checking those out.

Comment: @DocBrown currently, stops have a type: pick up, drop off, pit stop, and others. We also have a way to represent "the driver has reached their maximum driving hours for the day, so they need to sleep here".

Comment: @FilipMilovanović yes, good idea!

Comment: @Helena thanks for the suggestion. If I remember correctly, Eric Evans and Martin Fowler both use legs in their books.

Comment: What I'm missing in your description is how you'd want to store the "route" object, as a list (?) of legs/stops. Does every item belong to a route? How are they ordered?

Comment: From a real-world perspective, are you interested in the journey, or the departure/arrival aspects.  I'd lean toward legs if you are interested in the journey aspects and stops/stations if it's more about arrivals/departures.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil: I guess you misunderstood my question. Bergi above asked what the same what I wanted to know, in other words. What's a route based on "stops"? An ordered list of stops?

Comment: …or to extend this: what type of database are you using? A document-based one? A relational one? A graph database? Because an "ordered list" is hard to represent in a relational database, that's what @DocBrown and me are picking on.

Comment: @Bergi, we use a relational database, PostgreSQL specifically. An ordered list of stops is represented as rows with a position field indicating where that stop is in the route. Every route has at least four stops: depot, 1st customer stop, 2nd customer stop, depot. A depot is where vehicles are stored between trips. If I represented the same route as legs I'd have depot -> 1st cust stop, 1st cust stop->2nd cust stop, 2nd cust stop -> depot.

Comment: Pro tip: legs work great for shorter routes, but a stop can be very useful if you have the departure times right, to take full advantage of the bus factor.

Comment: @leftaroundabout [bus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor)???

Comment: @Bergi yes – the factor is estimated to be at least 2. That is, a bus can replace two legs (or even more, if it's a parallel bus), and it also gets you faster to the target (except in very short sprints).

Comment: You're effectively asking whether a polygon should be described by its vertices or by its edges. The answer is contextual. Is your domain focused on the stops they make, or on the travel between the stops? For example, a user might list a bunch of monuments they want to visit, which is stop-oriented, but if you're working with an Uber-like app, you're going to be interested travel (i.e. leg) related logic.

Answer (score 22):

> but I'm wondering if using legs would be better

When one has two alternative data structures representing the same thing, I would recommend against the assumption that one representation could be universally "better" than the other.

Semantically equivalent data structures may behave *differently* in regards to resource consumption, but often a structure which gives an increased performance for certain processes will do this on the expense of requiring more memory, or vice versa. Or, a data structure which is more performant for a process X might be slower when used for process Y. For many real-world case, however, these differences are completely negligible.

Hence one should pick what works well **for their specific use case** - if both approaches work well, one may start with the one which appears to be easier to implement, or the one which uses less redundancy (that's often the same, since redundancy can cause inconsistencies, and to deal with those correctly, one has to write and test extra code).  If that does not help for a decision, one should flip a coin.

The case you described may probably a case where the differences don't matter. The only use case for the data mentioned in the question was "description of a route" (for the purpose of bidding on it), not even something more complicated like path finding, and you wrote you don't have any real issues with it. Since the current approach seems to work well, I would recommend to stay with it. If you are in doubt, build a prototype using "legs" and evaluate its behaviour in comparison to the existing system.

Said that, I see actually one point here which could make difference: in the comments, you mentioned some requirements for **meta data related to "stops"** - stop types like *"pick up, drop off, pit stop, and others"*.  You did not mention similar meta data for "legs". This might be an indicator that both representations are *not really* equivalent, and that a "leg" representation may simply not be sufficient for the situation.

Moreover, these approaches are not mutually exclusive. In case you need also meta data for legs (like an information which road to take), you could implement a model which contains *both*:

- stops with location, arrival/departure times and meta data
- legs as a connection between to two stops, and "leg metadata" (but not with a arrival/departure time & location on their own)

So double check your requirements: are both representations *really* dual when it comes to meta data? Then it probably does not matter which one to pick. If not, you may not use either the one, or the other, but a combination of both.

Comment: Its entirely possible that both datastructures may be appropriate, with a transform at some point through the process from one to the other.

Comment: @user1937198:yes, I had that in mind, maybe I should have mentioned it as well.

Comment: +1 for "*you may need a combination of both*" (I skipped over the nodes in my answer since it had already been mentioned). I still think that departure and arrival times (in that order :P) should be part of the leg though. In a more complete model, departure and arrival might even be tables on their own, as the connection between a stop entity and a leg entity? Who knows.

Answer (score 11):

A route is just a [**path**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) in a [**graph**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) that is annotated with time information:

- A *leg* describes an **edge** in this path (`from`, `to`, `duration`), with a time annotation for either start or end of the edge.
- A *stop* describes a **node**/**vertice** in this path (`location`), with a time annotation related to an incoming and outgoing edges.

You will find in the more general graph-related literature a huge amount of articles on path finding algorithms using either the one or the other, and certainly some comparative analysis. The additional timing information is just decoration of the graph data with time information.

### Additional remarks

On my own limited experience in this area:

- I found the representation of a path as a succession of edges (so what you call legs) more powerful in complex graphs where many edges relate to the same vertices.
- The simpler and more elegant succession of nodes is fine as well, but you need to calculate or store the information about what happens between the nodes.

If you have to merge several routes (e.g. a train route with one carrier, followed by a truck route with another carrier):

- with the leg/edge approach, the overall route is just the concatenation of the partial routes (each edge can uniquely assigned to one carrier).
- with the stop/vertice approach, the overall route needs to duplicates vertices when you change transporter.

But in the end, whether you use one or the other, you can switch from the one to the other with some computations if you’ve kept the right annotations.

From the customer point of view, a representation of stops is very natural, since many bus stops in the world use this notation, and it allows a compact presentation of the schedule.

So it all depends on what you are the most interested in and use the most often.

A final remark is about your current algorithmic assets: if you have an existing system for which one approach worked well, and you have teams experimented with this approach, there may be an efficiency gain to keep this logic.

Comment: "I found the representation of a path as a succession of edges (so what you call legs) more powerful in complex graphs where many edges relate to the same vertices." - this is actually a downside if you don't care which one is taken!

Comment: @user253751 yes indeed. But its an advantage in typical route finding where you need to know which road or motorway you’d take to optimize your objectives (and know speed limits of each segment). It also depends if edges can be referred directly (i.e with a from/to model, you’d have a lot of redundant vertices).

Comment: in that case you would probably represent the objectives as points, because you don't care how to get from A to B as long as you arrive in B. And the route-finding algorithm would then return the route as links, because some links are better than others

Comment: From the question, it does not look like the OP having any route finding / graph search requirements.

Comment: @DocBrown route finding is not the only case where you might be interesting about whats between the nodes. All kind of constraints related to the path can be interesting as well. If you’re looking for heart transplants you may be interested by reducing time on road, because keeping thing cool is easier in the stations. If you’re bidding for parts of an A380, you may select longer routes but which can cope with large transporters. etc.  As said, I wanted to highlight that there are number of cases where edges are more useful than stops, but thzt in the end it depends on the needs.

Answer (score 10):

I would say it depends on what the suppliers are bidding on:

- If suppliers are bidding on providing services for a single leg, such as providing a truck to carry a package from point A to B, then it would be more natural to represent the data as legs.
- If suppliers are bidding on providing services at single stops, such as providing labor to unload from one truck and load another truck, then it would be more natural to represent the data as stops.
- If suppliers are bidding on handling the entire route, it doesn't really matter how you represent it, although stops probably fit better with how a user would initially build the route.

There's nothing particularly wrong with using both, either. I would consider this a fairly natural fit for a graph database because you have nodes and edges that are related with each other.

Answer (score 8):

When you have two data structures that are seemingly dual to each other for your purposes, look at the edge cases. In your example, that would be the empty route:

- A route with zero legs? Fine. A route with a single leg? Fine.
- A route with zero stops? Fine. A route with two stops? Fine. A route with a single stop? Wait…

Similarly, look at the start and end of each route. With a list of stops, you'd have some stops without an arrival and some stops without a departure, whereas a leg always has both - non-nullable data is easier to work with.

Sure, you might not want to model empty routes at all, so there might be an additional constraint that forbids these cases anyway. But thinking about their semantics, what they may represent if they were to occur, helps finding the more appropriate (or at least: more elegant) solution.

That said, the theoretically cleaner approach is not always the more practical one. Some database designs are better performing than others, despite (or: because) they are not properly normalised. So take a look at the (main/most important) queries you'd want run against these tables, and what constraints (like foreign keys, or checks like `departure_time < arrival_time`) you want to apply on these tables, and what indices you need. One approach might be easier to handle than the other.

Answer (score 1):

OK so once you have the data in memory its trivial to convert stops to legs and vice-versa.

Your problem will come when you are searching you database for particular sets of routes.

For example, I am at A and want to get to B in a single stop. If I am storing legs, I can search for rows in the database which depart A and arrive at B. If i am storing stops, I have to do a much more complicated search, getting multiple rows and their next and previous stops.

What kind of search you expect will determine how to store the data efficiently. I would imagine a hybrid approach might be best for the kind of train journey route you describe. ie A to D with stops B and C.